# 画像から女性の写真かどうかを判定する方法

Tags: 画像

SNSの画像を集めて、女性の写真のものだけを取り出す方法を探しているのですが、何か良い方法はありますか?
画像を集めるところまではできました。
画像の中には企業のロゴのような写真ですらないものも含まれています。

普段はrubyを使っているので、rubyで解決できると良いのですが、
「女性の写真かどうか」を判別する部分に関しては別の言語で解決することになっても大丈夫です。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4):

顔画像からの性別判定目的であれば、[OpenBR(Open Source Biometric Recognition)](http://openbiometrics.org/) を利用できるかもしれません。顔認識、年齢推定、性別推定をサポートしています。